# Is it possible to call methods dynamically?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, salesforce-lightning

I have 73 methods to execute in one test case[This is test to verify Auto merge rules in Salesforce]
As of now i am calling in the below manner :

```
SFHomePage rule_Test = new SFHomePage(driver, test);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, rule_Test);
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "About to start validation of Rule 1");
rule_Test.verifyRule1();   // Calling the method to verify Rule 1
test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Verification for Rule 1 is completed");
```

as mentioned in the above code i have to call all the 73 rules dynamically.

All the rules have separate methods to maintain the accountability.
I just tried the below manner but i know this will not work :

```
for(int i=1;i<43;i++)
    {
            test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "About to start validation of Rule "+i);
            rule_Test.verifyRule+i();   // Calling the method to verify Rule
            test.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Verification for Rule"+i+" is completed");
    }
```

Is there any way to call these methods dynamically ?

Comment: Is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: You might want to create a generic function like `verifyRule(int ruleNumber)` and inside that function you may call any rule depending on the ruleNumber (switch case?).

Comment: javascript is not the same as java

Comment: @Akaino : Yes this is JavaScript, thanks for your suggestion. That will work but concern here is i need to update the function definition for all the methods which i have already created.

Any other way which would help me not to update the existing method names ?

Comment: If these functions are members of `rule_Test` you can use `Object.keys(rule_test)` to grab an array of them, and `rule_Test[fn_name_variable]` to run them.

Comment: Why do you need to call them dynamically? Why aren't you testing them all? You could use a library like NUnit, JUnit to categorize them and call the categories as needed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) and `getMethod(String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)`. With this you could dynamically change method name and then invoke it. Heres the example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        Test test = new Test();
        for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
            String methodName = "verifyRule"+i;
            Method method = test.getClass()
                    .getMethod(methodName);
            method.invoke(test);
        }

    }

    public Test() {

    }

    public void verifyRule1() {
        logger.info("Verified rule 1");
    }

    public void verifyRule2() {
        logger.info("Verified rule 2");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52987', transport: 'socket'
14:36:47.243 [main] INFO Test - Verified rule 1
14:36:47.293 [main] INFO Test - Verified rule 2
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52987', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to invoke a method when method name is in string variable. You fetch the class then fetch the method then invoke the method. You can create loop and change the number in the end of the method name string everytime.

```
// get class.
Class<?> myClass = Class.forName("MyClassName");

// create object of class.
Object myClassObject= myClass.newInstance();

// get method from MyClassName class.
Method myMethod = myClassObject.getClass().getMethod("myMethodName");

// call/invoke myMethodName method.
 myMethod.invoke(myClassObject);
```